# Why is path stroke width bigger on MS Edge than other browsers?

Tags: html, css, svg, microsoft-edge

I'm making a SVG grid for my animations, and then I opened it in Microsoft Edge and see my paths are looking like this:
[image: Edge SVG Paths]
But I need them to look like this:
[image: Perfect look]

There's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/tf1ts1dg/)

And there's my SVG code

```
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M 0 100 L 50 0, M 50 0 L 100 100 ,M 100 100 L 0 50 ,M 0 50 L 100 0,M 100 0 L 0 100" class="first-line" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
    <path d="M 100 100 L 0 0, M 0 0 L 100 50, M 100 50 L 0 100, M 0 100 L 25 0, M 25 0 L 50 100, M 50 100 L 75 0, M 75 0 L 100 100" class="second-line stroke-width="1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
    <path d="M 50 100 L 0 0,   M 0 0 L 25 100,   M 25 100 L 50 0,   M 50 0 L 75 100,   M 75 100 L 100 0,   M 100 0 L 50 100" class="third-line"  vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
</svg>
```

Comment: because edge does not support vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below css for edge browser it can help full for you. check in edge browser.

See [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tf1ts1dg/3/)

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    .page .lines path {
        stroke-width:0.15px;
    }
}
```